# Using WFQ scheduling on ns2

Tags: simulation, ns2

I'm trying to use WFQ scheduling algorithm on NS2 (ver. 2.35)
I added the following implementation to NS2:
https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~varsha/allpapers/packet-scheduling/sim_code/ns2_packet_scheduling/src/

and wrote a simple dumbbell topology to test it:

```
set ns [new Simulator]

set nf [open trace.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

set tf [open trace.tr w]
$ns trace-all $tf

proc finish {} {
        global ns tf nf
        $ns flush-trace
        close $tf
        close $nf
        exec nam trace.nam &
        exit 0
}

Simulator instproc get-link { node1 node2 } {
    $self instvar link_
    set id1 [$node1 id]
    set id2 [$node2 id]
    return $link_($id1:$id2)
}

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set R1 [$ns node]
set R2 [$ns node]

$ns duplex-link $n0 $R1 10Mb 1ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $R1 10Mb 1ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $R1 $R2 1Mb 3ms WFQ
$ns duplex-link $R2 $n1 10Mb 1ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $R2 $n3 10Mb 1ms DropTail


set l [$ns get-link $R1 $R2]
set q [$l queue]

$q buckets 6
$q bandwidth 100
$q blimit 10000
$q mask 0
$q quantum 0 .40
$q quantum 1 .60

$ns queue-limit $R1 $R2 10

$ns duplex-link-op $R1 $n0 orient left-up
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $R2 orient left-down
$ns duplex-link-op $R1 $R2 orient right
$ns duplex-link-op $n2 $R1 orient right-up
$ns duplex-link-op $R2 $n3 orient right-down

$ns duplex-link-op $R1 $R2 queuePos 0.5

set tcp0 [new Agent/TCP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $tcp0
set tcpsink0 [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $tcpsink0

set udpsink0 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n3 $udpsink0

set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$udp0 set class_ 6
$ns attach-agent $n2 $udp0


set ftp0 [new Application/FTP]
$ftp0 attach-agent $tcp0

set cbr [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr set packetSize_ 500
$cbr set rate_ 1Mb
$cbr attach-agent $udp0

$ns connect $udp0 $udpsink0
$ns connect $tcp0 $tcpsink0

$ns at 0.1 "$ftp0 start"
$ns at 0.1 "$cbr start"
$ns at 300.0 "$ftp0 stop"
$ns at 300.0 "$cbr stop"
$ns at 305.0 "finish"

$ns run
```

But after running simulation I get

```
No active flow
No active flow
No active flow
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

While the implementaion example ([here](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~varsha/allpapers/packet-scheduling/sim_code/ns2_packet_scheduling/examples/ex1.tcl) ) works (it only gives `No  active flow` messages but not the `Floating point exception (core dumped)` )

Comment: ? ?  Are the default examples working OK ? http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~varsha/allpapers/packet-scheduling/sim_code/final.tgz >>> /final/examples/

Comment: @KnudLarsen: yes they run without the `Floating point exception` while they still produce `No active flow` (that is implemented in `wfq.c` ) but it is working and produces the output traces